# Key Error when defining string, python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key

I get the error "Key error:'name' "

Can anyone tell what the problem is with the following code:

```
import random

def mongoCountry(countryNum, provinceNum):
    """generate some test data"""
    f = open("F:\\univData\\country-mongo.json", mode = 'w')
    text = ""
    for c_n in range(0, countryNum):
        for p_n in range(0, provinceNum):
            text += "{name:country{0},provinces:[{$ref : Province,$id :   province{1}}]}\n".format(c_n, p_n)
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

mongoCountry(2, 10)
```

I googled it so I know it's about dict() object. but I can't find any such object there.

Comment: will you please give detail error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your program correctly, you are trying to create a JSON object. As iCodez said in his answer, Python's `format` function treats the entire string as the format string (or template string, if you like). To override that, you can escape the format strings like this

```
"{{name:country{0},provinces:[{{$ref : Province,$id : province{1}}}]}}\n".format(c_n, p_n)
```

You will get something like the following if `c_n` and `p_n` are `"Welcome"` and `"123"`

```
{name:countryWelcome,provinces:[{$ref : Province,$id :   province123}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.format` is treating the entire string as a format field because it begins with `{name:` and ends with `}`.  Below is a demonstration with a simpler string:

```
>>> '{a:{0}}'.format(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
>>>
```

To fix the problem, you can use the [old `%` formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
text += "{name:country%i,provinces:[{$ref : Province,$id :   province%i}]}\n" % (c_n, p_n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your string with `{name:` so `format` need `name` as a key.

Please escape `{` before name.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples